# flask jinja2 variable of variable

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am trying to access a variable of a object in jinja2 using this code:

```
{% for row in rows.items %}
  <tr>
    {% for column in model_settings['table_columns'] %}
      <td>
        <p>{{ row.column }}</p>
      </td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

what I want is if column was username I would want it to give me
`row.username`. sorry for the bad explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja2 has the builtin [`attr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.attr) filter to access an attribute of an object. The name of the attribute can be a static string, or in your case: a string stored in a variable:

```
{% for row in rows.items %}
  <tr>
    {% for column in model_settings['table_columns'] %}
      <td>
        <p>{{ row|attr(column) }}</p>
      </td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```